# jquery triggerHandler multiple parameters

Tags: jquery

According to the jquery manual:

> .triggerHandler( eventType [, extraParameters ] )
>
> where extraParameters is an array

If I have passed only one parameters ok but if I try to pass multiples parameters not work. Only first parameter of array is available

```js
 $('#test')
 
 .off('test_event')
 
 .on('test_event',function(event,parameters){
   console.log(parameters); // return 1 not array
  })
  
 .click(function(){
  $(this).triggerHandler('test_event',[1,2,3,4]);
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id = "test">
 test
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements passed in an array in a click handler are separated out into independent parameters. As such, they need to be assigned to the `function()` itself. You have four elements in your array, so you need to pass four variables to the function:

```js
$('#test')
  .off('test_event')
  .on('test_event', function(event, a, b, c, d) {
    console.log(a, b, c, d);
  })
  .click(function() {
    $(this).triggerHandler('test_event', [1, 2, 3, 4]);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test">
 test
</button>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

The number of arguments in your click handler needs to match what you're passing it. When a normal click event fires, all the arguments will be undefined, but when you trigger it and pass the array, the values are separated into individual parameters.

```js
$('#test')
  .off('test_event')
  .on('test_event', function(event, a, b, c, d) {
    console.log(a, b, c, d);
  })
  .click(function() {
    $(this).triggerHandler('test_event', [1, 2, 3, 4]);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test">
 test
</button>
```

Comment: I have accepted @Obsidians answer because He has been first () ( 30 seconds before )